# Does this parametric curve have a name?

Tags: polar-coordinates, curves, parametric

I have a curve parameterized by
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x(t)=\frac{k\sin{t}}{t}\\y(t)=\frac{k(1-\cos{t})}{t}.\\\end{array}\right.$$
In polar form, this is
$$r^2=\frac{2k^2(1-\cos{\theta})}{\theta^2}.$$
I was wondering if this curve has a name. I found it to be the trajectory of the center of mass of a uniform sector as the central angle of the sector varies, where $k=\frac{2}{3}R$ and $R$ is the radius of the sector.

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to $$r=\pm\frac{k\sin{(\theta/2)}}{\theta/2}$$which is the sinc function.